# How to export animation from Blender to XCode?

Tags: xcode, macos, animation, scenekit

I create one new SceneKit Game in oSX, and drag the panda.scn and walk.scn from Apple WWDC FoxBuildingaSceneKitGamewiththeXcodeSceneEditor sample code into the project, it animates.

But when I create my own 3D model and animation, it doesn’t work.

If there is vetex group int he animation, XCode throw error, there is one joint in the DAE. Then how to design animation in Blender without vetex group?

if there is sub-bone in the DAE for animation, XCode also throw error on joint.

Appreciate anyone could share one complete sample with simple geometry and simple animation (vetex group?), which can run in XCode.
Thanks.

I have followed below steps on export DAE.

[how to export and set up animation files from Blender3D](http://trac.wildfiregames.com/wiki/AnimationExportTutorial)